# Как корректно вставить рисунок в HTML задним фоном

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Как без использвания Css прямо в html вставить ссылку на фоновое изображение (background-image) для всей страницы ?

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Main for inputs params for Kovach signals</title>
    <link type ="text/css" href="{% static 'almaz/css/styles.css'%}" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
<div style="background-image: url('/static/almaz/images/fon-image.jpg');"></div>   #--- > ??? не знаю
    <h2 class="head_text">Управление данными в json files</h2>
    <hr/>
    <form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
    <table>
        {{ form }}
    </table>
    <input class="myButton" type="submit" value="Save to json_file" >
</form>
</div>-->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ну если для всей страницы, то наверное это надо делать у тега body или html

Comment: да и так пробовал,  куда тока не вставлял этот код не работет :/

Comment: «Не работает» это плохое описание проблемы. Что именно не работает?

Comment: рисунок фоном не хочет, как бы не видит его

Answer (score 2):

Не вижу проблемы. Всё работает:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Main for inputs params for Kovach signals</title>
  <link type="text/css" href="{% static 'almaz/css/styles.css'%}" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body style="background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/tWGMC.jpg');">
  <div></div> #--- > ??? не знаю
  <h2 class="head_text">Управление данными в json files</h2>
  <hr/>
  <form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <table>
      {{ form }}
    </table>
    <input class="myButton" type="submit" value="Save to json_file">
  </form>
  </div>-->
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: :)) THanks .....